# Comparison of fields that exist

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

If I have an array of objects and need to find something in it, I could use `find` function of underscore/lodash

```
let part = { id: 'foo' };
_.find(arr, p => p.id === part.id);
```

This is easy. Now what about multiple properties?

```
let part = { id: 'foo', name: 'part foo' };
_.find(arr, p => p.id === part.id && p.name === part.name);
```

But hold on. What if I need a function that would compare by `id` first, and then if `name` exists then compares by `name`, and then maybe by other fields that exist in `part`. Doing this doesn't seem to be right:

```
_.find(arr, p => {
                  return p.id === part.id
                  && (part.name && p.name === part.name)
                  && (part.title && p.title === part.title);
});
```

It would fail to find a part if `title` exists and `name` doesn't.
Also what if I have longer list of properties to compare, can I avoid having bloated body of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return p.id === part.id
&& (!part.name || p.name === part.name)
&& (!part.title || p.title === part.title);
```

Doing it like this makes it treat any property that doesn't exist in `part` as matching, so it only does a real comparison for the properties that exist.

This abbreviated syntax also assumes that valid values of `part.X` are never falsy. You can make it safer with:

```
return p.id === part.id
&& (!part.hasOwnProperty("name") || p.name === part.name)
&& (!past.hasOwnProperty("title") || p.title == part.title);
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Another example of why exactly operator precedence and associativity in imperative languages including javascript sucks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with precedence or associativity. Your logic was simply wrong.

Comment: Your logic treats a missing field as a mismatch, rather than ignoring the field.

Comment: What do you mean has nothing to do? it short-circuits based on rules of precedence innit?. Logical NOT is higher and then AND and then OR. My point is - in the end it makes it difficult to read and reason about code like this if you don't know what exactly happening.

Comment: My answer has the same grouping with parentheses as your code. The problem is that you need to use OR, not AND, and invert the test for the property. Your logic was inverted.

Comment: No, I'm not complaining about your answer. It seems to be working. Just in general - to have to write code like this makes me sad.

Comment: If you find this confusing, you could write separate `if` statements. No one is forcing you to turn it into a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of options....

You could make a dedicated comparison function  `isPartEqual(p, part)`

```
_.find(arr, p => isPartEqual(p, part));
```

or you could create  `compareIfExists(p,part,['id','name','title'])`

or if "part" contains all the fields you want to match, then in lodash

```
_.findWhere(arr, part)
```

Comment: It's If I've had asked "how could I calculate the area of a triangle" and you'd said - start with a ruler. Your answer seem to be helpful, yet I'm not sure how...